# Rep Recalc for All Moderator Nominees

Tags: support, reputation, moderators, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should moderator nominees have their reputations recalculated?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/should-moderator-nominees-have-their-reputations-recalculated)

Well, I just recalced and lost a few hundred points, it might not be a bad idea for everyone else to do the same in the interest of full disclosure.

Purely voluntary of course.

Comment: Mine matches at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I've been meaning to do that.

Comment: I just did it too.

Comment: I generally try to recalc once a week, and I just happened to recalc yesterday, so no change.

Comment: Why this is not automatic?

Comment: @Pierre - until relatively recently you had to ask a moderator to recalculate your rep - it was seen to be an expensive operation. Either that view has changed or edits were made to improve the code (hence it's availability to all on the /reputation page). However, I suspect that even a weekly recalc of *everyone's* rep would be quite time consuming.

Comment: Mine is correct at the moment too.