# Should moderator nominees have their reputations recalculated?

Tags: discussion, reputation, election

Last election, there was [a suggestion that nominees should have their reputations recalculated](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1071/8) to accurately reflect their current totals and take into account all activity taken on the site thus far.

Back then, it wasn't done automatically, but several candidates took it upon themselves to do it anyway by going to the [Reputation page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/reputation) and clicking "Trigger Reputation Recalc".

I don't remember if the feature existed back then, but moderators *can* recalculate anyone's reputation now: should it be done for nominees? If you're a nominee, would you mind recalculating your reputation yourself?

Comment: I would support it.

Comment: Way ahead of you :)

Comment: Ouch, I lost 885 points.  How do you un-recalc?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I feel your pain. I lost 1300-ish at one point. :)

Comment: Why it's not automatic?

Comment: I lost 1269 reputation, but I still have my limited moderator powers so I can continue to rule with an iron fist ;-)

Comment: @Pierre303 Related [MSO feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75530/rep-recalc-on-all-nominees-for-election).

Comment: @MarkTrapp I think you should go ahead and do it, a bit closer to the end of the nomination phase. The 12 upvotes the question already got are enough to indicate that the community likes the idea.

Comment: I wouldn't mind as I have done it very recently and I don't believe it will make much a difference (if any). Although, even if I had never done so, I believe it is only fair.

Comment: @maple_shaft `limited moderator powers ` meaning are there different types of moderators?

Comment: @PresleyDias Users with 10k reputation or more have access to [so-called "moderator" tools](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools), which are a subset of the tools elected—or diamond—moderators get access to.

Comment: Rep Normalized -182

Answer (score 7):

Would this even matter? Given the list of current candidates, most are active enough that their presence is far more telling than their reputation anyway, I really don't think the change would be a significant change either way.  Also we only have 9 nominations so far, so I doubt we are going to get to the point where someone might get left out of a primary due to rep inaccuracies which would be the only concern I would have.

Comment: Agreed... there is more to Reputation than well... Reputation :)  I sometimes wonder if reputation should be something convoluted like the Plus-Minus stats in ice hockey, but then nobody would be able to understand how its calculated and then everybody would ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

I was personally planning on doing it closer to the transition from nomination to either primary or election, and if there was a primary, again just before the election if I made it that far. If anyone wants me to do it sooner, comment here and I'd be more than happy to do it immediately.

Personally, I would be in favor of a recalc right before the voting begins for everyone. Might as well give the voters a complete picture and accurate stats.

However, I don't plan on releasing my long-form birth certificate nor my income taxes for any number of years. So, yeah. That's off the table. :P